# Gauss Elimination - Diagonal dominant matrices don't need row changes

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

I was asked to prove the following statement:

let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix with real entries such that $\forall k \in \mathbb N, k\leq n$: $$\sum_{i \neq k} |A_{i,k}| < |A_{kk}|$$

Show that if we were to do gauss elimination (or LU factorization) of $A$, then there will be no need for row changes, no need for partial pivoting.

I don't see why this is true, I'd appreciate a hint in the right direction. Maybe I should take a general $n$ by $n$ matrix that is diagonly dominant, try to $LU$ factor it and see that I don't need row changes? is this the way?

Comment: By row changes do you mean just multiplying a row by a scalar, or can we not even take one row from another?

Comment: I mean switching row placement. for example row 1 becomes row3 and row3 becomes row1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when row pivoting happens, there is a hierarchy, and we swap rows, so that the new row's diagonal entry is largest, but for a diagonally dominant matrix, the diagonal is always largest, so no pivoting/ row swapping is needed, just subtracting rows from other rows etc.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but what I don't understand is, at first the diagonal is dominant, we were given that, so there is no need to change the first row. We then do gauss elimination and turn all the values in the column 1 (apart from the first value) 0. How do we know now that the entry at $(2,2)$ is largest at its row? it was before we did gauss elimination, but we don't know whats the new situation. How do we know that subtracting rows from rows won't change the "hierarchy" of the values in each row

Comment: Thats a good point, I will think about it some more

Comment: I think it would have to do with the fact that to subtract the 1st row from the second, making say entry $(2,1)$ zero, means that you have to multiply row 1 by a scalar, making the 1st entry small enough to take off (2,1), but in doing so it is smaller than (2,2). and by diagonal dominance, all the entries of the 1st row are much smaller, so our result again is a diagonal dominant row.

Comment: "making say entry (2,1) zero, means that you have to multiply row 1 by a scalar, making the 1st entry small enough to take off (2,1), " not always. It could be that $(2,1)$ is larger than $(1,1)$ and then you have to increase the values in the first row in order to take off $(2,1)$

Comment: But then (2,2) would be even larger then

Answer (score 10):

We only need to show that after eliminating $a_{2,1}$, diagonal dominance is preserved, i.e.,
$$
\left|a_{2,2}-a_{1,2}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|>\sum_{i=3}^n\left|a_{2,i}-a_{1,i}{a_{2,1}\over a_{1,1}}\right|,
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
|a_{2,2}a_{1,1}-a_{1,2}a_{2,1}|>\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|.
$$
But this is true:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}a_{1,1}-a_{1,i}a_{2,1}|&\le& 
|a_{1,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{2,i}|+|a_{2,1}|\sum_{i=3}^n|a_{1,i}| \\
&<& |a_{1,1}|(|a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}|)+|a_{2,1}|(|a_{1,1}|-|a_{1,2}|) \\
&=&|a_{1,1}||a_{2,2}|-|a_{2,1}||a_{1,2}|\\
&\le& |a_{1,1}a_{2,2}-a_{2,1}a_{1,2}|
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: why did you sum starting from $3$?

Comment: Why $\sum_{i=3} a_{1,i}<(|a_{1,1}|-|a_{1,2}|)$?

Comment: For the first question: you are considering the sub-matrix $A(2:n, 2:n)$ so the first diagonal entry is $A_{2,2}$. You need to show that the absolute value is greater than the sum of the absolute values of all the other entries in the column, those entries start at $i = 3$.